# Creating a namespace object from string to call a function?

Tags: jquery, javascript

i have a namespace object `form.iso.methodName` as a string and i want to call that method. I cant create namespace object like [form][iso][methodName]

```
split : function(ns) { // ns namespace is object
    var splitNameSpace = ns.split('.');
    var methodName = splitNameSpace.pop();
    //console.log(splitNameSpace);
    var content = [];

    for (var i=0;i<splitNameSpace.length;i++){
        content = [splitNameSpace[i]];
        console.log(content);
    }
```

**Update- Found solution  **

```
split : function(ns) {
    var splitNameSpace = ns.split('.');
    var methodName = splitNameSpace.pop();
    //console.log(splitNameSpace);
    var content = [];
    var obj;
    for (var i=0;i<splitNameSpace.length;i++){
        obj = [splitNameSpace[i]];
    content = content+"["+obj+"]";

    }
```

Comment: Could you try to explain a bit better what you want to do?

Comment: @AndrewMcGivery i am passing a namespace string in function split parameter and i want that function to split up and build namespace object [form][iso[methodName] so i can call a function which is in different namespace object.. i hope i explained .i am bad at english

Comment: So, if I'm to understand, you want to call form.iso.methodName() given the string "form.iso.methodName"?

Comment: @AndrewMcGivery yes but the form.iso is namespace object

Comment: Couldn't you just call eval(ns+'()') ?

Comment: @codefactor i read in almost all articles that eval is not a safe way to do it

Comment: @user2125700 The safety of `eval` is only dependent upon your trust of the input argument `ns` - you could validate the input string using a regex like `[\w\.]` and then the evaluated result would be ensured to be a simple dot notation (combination of word characters and periods) and it cannot contain script or other special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function namespace(ns){
    var d, o;
    n = ns.split('.');
    o = window[n[0]] = window[n[0]] || {};
    var l = n.length;
    for(var i=1; i<l; i++){
        o = o[n[i]] = o[n[i]] || {};
    }
    return o;
}

 var param = 'foo.bar.blah.methodName',
     method = param.split('.').pop(),
     ns = param.split('.').slice(0,-1).join('.'),
     obj = namespace(ns); 

 obj[method]();
```

You can improve this by retrieving the global object instead of using `window`

Comment: i cant get it and i am trying to pop the last ns after split for method name and the rest as namespace object but i dont understand what you are doing?

Comment: You can call namespace to retrieve the namespace of your method: `var param = 'foo.bar.blah.methodName'; method = ns.split('.').pop(); ns = param.split('.').slice(0,-1).join('.'); obj = namespace(ns); obj[method]();`

Comment: i found out the solution bit untidy but works `split : function(ns) {
  var splitNameSpace = ns.split('.');
  var methodName = splitNameSpace.pop();
  //console.log(splitNameSpace);
  var content = [];
  var obj;
  for (var i=0;i<splitNameSpace.length;i++){
   obj = [splitNameSpace[i]];
   //console.log(obj);
   content = content+"["+obj+"]";
   //var cont = content[splitNameSpace[i]];
   //content = cont;
   //cont = content[i];
   //console.log(content);
   //console.log(methodName);
  }`

Comment: wow - exactly what i needed and it works! One comment: in function namespace the variable d is not used.